# Why can't I return a unique_ptr from a pair?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, rvalue-reference, std-pair, perfect-forwarding

Why can't I return a unique_ptr from a pair?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

unique_ptr<int> get_value() {
    pair<unique_ptr<int>, int> p(unique_ptr<int>(new int(3)), 4);
    return p.first;
}

int main(void) {
    cout << *get_value() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this with g++ 4.6, I get:

```
../main.cpp: In function ‘std::unique_ptr<int> get_value()’:
../main.cpp:9:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int, _Dp = std::default_delete<int>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unique_ptr.h:256:7: error: declared here
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand the error message

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is move-only.

Comment: how is this not move-only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` does not have a copy constructor, and the way in which you are returning it (as a member of a local object) does not qualify for automatic move.  You need to specify the move manually in this case.

```
return std::move(p.first);
```

Comment: How do I know what does qualify for automatic move?

Comment: @dspyz: Give me a minute to look up the reference, but it's the same conditions that qualify it for return value optimization.

Comment: @dspyz: Check 12.8 paragraphs 31 and 32 : http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf

Comment: @dspyz, To expand, it would qualify if you just did `std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3)); return p;`.